# Can't run example pyspark code on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

**Background**

We have installed a standalone spark cluster on three RHEL 7 VMs, running Spark 3.0.0. Intending to use Pyspark.

We have one master node and two worker nodes.
Spark is started on all three nodes, we can connect to the master node GUI and see the workers. The spark processes have been started with the standard shell scripts and are confirmed running on all three nodes.

On any of the three nodes we can do:

`./bin/spark-submit /usr/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py '/usr/spark/LICENSE'`

and it runs without a problem.

But if we try to submit it to the master node:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://<server>:7077 /usr/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py '/usr/spark/LICENSE'´
```

it hangs with the following error:

```
"Exception in thread "map-output-dispatcher-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no zstd-jni in java.library.path
Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /linux/amd64/libzstd-jni.so or load zstd-jni from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni in your system."
```

And so on.

On the worker nodes I can see:

```
20/09/23 15:20:25 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/usr/spark/conf/:/usr/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=42395" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<server>:42395" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "10.204.197.207" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20200923152025-0043" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@10.204.197.207:4043"
```

On the master node I can see the following:

```
20/09/23 15:36:13 INFO Master: Registering app PythonWordCount
20/09/23 15:36:13 INFO Master: Registered app PythonWordCount with ID app-20200923153613-0044
20/09/23 15:36:13 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20200923153613-0044/0 on worker worker-20200923082826-10.204.197.207-4043
20/09/23 15:36:13 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20200923153613-0044/1 on worker worker-20200923082812-10.204.197.208-4043
20/09/23 15:36:13 WARN Master: App app-20200923153613-0044 requires more resource than any of Workers could have.
20/09/23 15:36:13 WARN Master: App app-20200923153613-0044 requires more resource than any of Workers could have.
```

It warns on resources but I've tried to reduce those to a bare minimum - still getting the same result. I'm assuming that it's just a warning.

**Investigation:**

Taking the error message literally I've tried to troubleshoot **zstd-jni**.

- I can connect to the webuis both for the workers and the master. The job is visible but it gets stuck on this java error.
- I can see that the the zstd-jni-1.4.4-3.jar package is available in /usr/spark/jars.
- I can see that the path to /usr/spark/jars/* is being specified when the job is submitted on the worker.
- I have installed zstd on the Linux VMs, but that didn't help.
- There are no firewalls between the nodes.

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Feels like I'm missing something fairly simple (especially since I haven't touched Java in 20 years) but I'm at a loss.

Comment: What's the version of lib-zstd that you have installed in the VM?
I am wondering if RHEL7 is too old of an OS. It might have a version of lib-zstd that is not compatible with Spark

Comment: Actually, I got the same when trying it on RHEL8 and Java 11 as a second attempt. But I found a workaround, the actual libzstd-jni.so file is included in the zstd-jni-1.4.4-3.jar file. If I extracted the so-file and put it in a directory where java looks for library files, then it works. But it shouldn't be needed as the java code should be able to use the file within the jar.