# Error running PySpark code in Jupyter Notebook on RaspberryPi Cluster with Hadoop/Spark/Yarn

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, jupyter-notebook, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run example code in Jupyter Notebook with PySpark using Yarn cluster.

I think my cluster works fine. I can see all nodes running

```console
yarn node -list -all
OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Total Nodes:3
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
       pi2:40045                RUNNING          pi2:8042                                  0
       pi1:38067                RUNNING          pi1:8042                                  0
       pi3:35139                RUNNING          pi3:8042                                  0
```

I'm using example notebook available here: https://github.com/dmanning21h/pi-cluster/blob/master/notebooks/picluster.ipynb

I can run all the notebook code except this cell:

```python
# Show label counts by class
df.groupBy("label") \
    .count() \
    .orderBy(col("count").desc()) \
    .show()
```

Spark gets stuck on this job with following error:

```console
Exception in thread "map-output-dispatcher-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/hadoop/lib/native/libzstd-jni.so: /opt/hadoop/lib/native/libzstd-jni.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /linux/arm/libzstd-jni.so or load zstd-jni from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni in your system.
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2659)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:73)
        at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:60)
        at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdOutputStream.<clinit>(ZstdOutputStream.java:15)
        at org.apache.spark.io.ZStdCompressionCodec.compressedOutputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.serializeMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:913)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.$anonfun$serializedMapStatus$2(MapOutputTracker.scala:210)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.withWriteLock(MapOutputTracker.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.serializedMapStatus(MapOutputTracker.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster$MessageLoop.run(MapOutputTracker.scala:457)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "map-output-dispatcher-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdOutputStream
        at org.apache.spark.io.ZStdCompressionCodec.compressedOutputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.serializeMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:913)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.$anonfun$serializedMapStatus$2(MapOutputTracker.scala:210)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.withWriteLock(MapOutputTracker.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.serializedMapStatus(MapOutputTracker.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster$MessageLoop.run(MapOutputTracker.scala:457)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've also tried sollution from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029599/cant-run-example-pyspark-code-on-standalone-cluster#comment113629179_64029599) but it's not working.

Comment: You don't need native libraries for a functional cluster, but apparently you need to build/install zstd for ARM if you want to use them. Personally, I'd try to use k3s with Spark rather than introduce more JVM overhead of YARN on limited memory

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've built zstd from source, unpacked .jar to get libzstd-jni.so file and copied it to hadoop/lib/native/ but still i get the same error. Should I do it diffrently?
Error:
`WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 17, pi1, executor 2): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no zstd-jni in java.library.path
Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /linux/arm/libzstd-jni.so or load zstd-jni from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni in your system.`

Comment: Maybe you need to restart the JVM for the libraries to load? I'm not sure, though